# Check if model has locale_restriction in scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, localization, internationalization

Consider a model Post which has a `title`, `description` and a `locale_restrictions` field.

The locale restrictions field specifies in which locales the post should be displayed. It contains a CSV value: `en,de,be,nl`.

What I would like to do is use either a default_scope or a named scope to only return the model instances for a specific locale. Something like (with a `localized` scope): `Post.localized.all`. This scope then looks at the current locale `I18n.locale` and returns the posts that have that locale in their `locale_restrictions` CSV.

I cannot seem to get this working, having tried quite a couple of options. The closest I came was with a SQL `LIKE` expression:

```
default_scope -> { where("locale_restrictions LIKE (?)", "%#{I18n.locale.to_s}%") }
```

However, this fails when there's, for example, both a `:en` and `:benl` locale, since `%en%` will match `:benl`.

Apparently you can't get access to `self.locale_restrictions` within a scope. `self` returns the class instead of the instance. I can't figure out a way to split the locale_restrictions and check them.

What would be the best way to go about this using scopes, or are there any *best practices* regarding localizing database that I'm missing out on?

I'm basically looking for an easy way to scope my controller instance variables to a specific locale. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using LIKE you can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) and include beginning-of-word and end-of-word boundries in the regular expression.  This should do the trick:

```
default_scope -> { where("locale_restrictions REGEXP (?)", "[[:<:]]#{I18n.locale.to_s}[[:>:]]") }
```